# "Failed to import the site module" when running pip --version

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip

I am using mac OS X, but am running into some trouble when I try to download pip to my terminal. If I type: `python --version`, I get the message that I have python 3.7 downloaded. So I would assume that I also have pip. But when I type `pip --version`, this message comes up on my terminal:

```
Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to import the site module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'site'
```

I attempted to download pip because I thought this might be occurring because I did not have it downloaded in the first place, but the same error message occurred during the download.